# Flask framework in Qpython Android platform

Tags: flask, qpython

Is it possible to run flask framework on Android platform using Qpython ? If yes please instruct steps to configure

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a few minutes to go over the [site tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and what's [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site. Your question needs to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is installing it through pip_console.py : )

Then you can develop flask project with your pc or mac, and upload it into your device to run.

[QPython development environment using mac or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511359/qpython-development-environment-using-mac-or-windows/)

Comment: I am able to install Flask using pip_console.py but to run flask project. It's giving flask import error

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but only on the first version of it. 
You go on libraries, than you choose install with official pypi.
When pypi run, write pip install flask.
It's done!
Be happy