# QPython development environment using mac or windows

Tags: android, python, sl4a, qpython

Being new to QPython, didn't find any reference
about developing on a Mac or Pc, eventually 
deploying the code on the Android device.

In contrast to developing the code itself on the Android device
which seems very awkward specially for larger projects.

I wish to write the code using a "normal" IDE such as IntelliJ
using my Mac or Windows, eventually deploy it on an Android device, 
and execute with QPython.

So the following questions come to mind:

1. Best practice to transfer source code to an Android device with QPython installed (not using the QR Code which is limited to few KB's of code)
2. Is it possible to develop QPython code on Mac/Windows namely using the SL4A (androidhelper) or is it strictly available on the Android device itself

I have more questions but would be better to have the basic best practices.

Ps. to give a context in relation to question #1 we need to rapidly deploy QPython code on many devices quickly, so copying the .py files manually is out of the question, and the QR code feature is very limited, so perhaps create a script that imports a script? (via git or HTTP)

Comment: You could create a standalone APK using Kivy's [python-for-android](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android) project - although maintained by the Kivy project, it can also create an APK that just runs a python script before closing (rather than displaying a gui).

Comment: Yes, for now it looks like Kivy should be a more adequate alternative at least until QPython makes more sense for developing real world applications and not just playing around...

Answer (score 2):

You can develop qpython project as other python projects with your pc or MC, and upload the project into your mobile's /sdcard/com.hipipal.qpyplus/projects/ then run it in qpython.

The qpython project should contain the main.py which is used for the project first launch script.

Besides adb (android develop tool), you can use the qpython's FTP service ( You could find it in setting page ) or other FTP app to upload the project into your mobile.

GOOD NEWS: In the newest qpython(1.2.2), it contains a qedit4web.py which allow you develop from browser and edit and run code from your mobile.